# Application received signal SIGSEGV cannot be located

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, crash, stack-trace

how can I locate the code where exception raised like below?

this only happened on few devices like iPhone6 run iOS 10

[xcode stack trace screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqxTO.png)

and also

```
Application received signal SIGSEGV (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001831e01d8 <redacted> + 148
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000181c1855c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001831e0108 <redacted> + 0
3   xxx                            0x100464a00 xxx + 4606464
4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x000000018226f338 _sigtramp + 36
5   UIKit                               0x000000018902b588 <redacted> + 80
6   QuartzCore                          0x00000001864ee448 <redacted> + 208
7   QuartzCore                          0x00000001864e30e8 <redacted> + 292
8   QuartzCore                          0x00000001864e2fa8 <redacted> + 32
9   QuartzCore                          0x000000018645fc64 <redacted> + 252
10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001864870d0 <redacted> + 512
11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000186487af0 <redacted> + 120
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018318d7dc <redacted> + 32
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018318b40c <redacted> + 372
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001830ba068 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15  WebCore                             0x0000000187c5ba2c <redacted> + 456
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182273860 <redacted> + 240
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182273770 <redacted> + 0
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000182270dbc thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Does it happen on application launch? Or does it happen when you open a specific view controller? Or does it happen when you press a specific button? You can add an exception breakpoint and see where it breaks, or you can set specific breakpoints in your classes for right before it breaks, if you know when it happens.

Comment: show your code where you getting crash?

Comment: @KaylaGalway this kind of crash only happened on a few devices, and I cann't reproduce the crash. it happened while the UIWebView loading a request .it's quite weird.

Comment: That is too broad to troubleshoot.